# Samsung S20 launches apps with different screen densities

Tags: android, screen-density, samsung

I test an application display problems on a Samsung S20 device.

When I log the display metrics of the device, here is what it returns me, density of the screen is xxhdpi 480 (x3) :
[image]

Now this is the weird part, **I'm just changing the application id of my application**, and I launch again the application and now when I log the display metrics, here is waht it returns me, density of the screen is xhdpi 360 (x2.25) :
[image]

Note that I've tested it with a sample android app created from the android studio "new module" menu entry, and I get the same results for the screen density, I only change the "applicationId" in the build.graddle, and the screen density of the s20 changes!

[image]

I've tested the app with different application ids, there is no rule, some times the app starts in density 480, and sometimes the app starts in density 360. I can't see any pattern in the application id, but the density is consistent for a given application id, if I don't change the application id, the density is the same every time I start the app.

The display problems appear when the density of the device is 360 (x2.25), but not when the density is 480 (x3).

I didn't even know it was possible to have different screen densities on the same device. Anybody has a clue ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is your app a game? If so on samsung devices there are "samsung game launcher" and "samsung game booster" apps which know which packageId is game and can run it in changed density environment https://stackoverflow.com/q/51014494/1372866