# Android Native Size is 1920x1200 however the GLSurface is 1440x900?

Tags: android, size, tablet, glsurfaceview

Android Native Size is 1920x1200 however the GLSurface is 1440x900?

Not sure what is misconfigured for these Large DPI screens here

> CurrentMode:{id=1, width=1200, height=1920, fps=60.000004}
> refreshRate: [60.000004] mode PhysicalWidth:[1200] mode
> PhysicalHeight:[1920]
>
> ViewRootImpl@24dd063[OFActivity]: Relayout returned:
> old=(0,0,1920,1200) new=(0,0,1440,900) req=(0,0)8 dur=65 res=0x1
> s={false 0} ch=false fn=-1 D/OF: Create surface

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer / Same Problem

> What is causing this problem is an online check to
> https://service.game-mode.net (parameter: package name) during
> installation on Samsung devices. This may cause a change of the
> default resolution, e.g. if the app is known as a 'game' (my app is a
> board game). This can be changed by the user using a game performance
> tuning service such as Game Launcher. This is available for all
> Samsung phones and most Samsung tablets. But as it happens not for my
> tablet, a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 2019 (SM-T510). After contacting
> Samsung Developers support they changed the settings for this device
> type, so that now my app runs in native resolution;

[Codename One app running in lower resolution (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61752978/codename-one-app-running-in-lower-resolution-android)