# Why is the button looks weird on android compared to iOS?

Tags: codenameone

I use the same theme to build iOS and Android. But the android version looks weird compared with iOS. The padding of the button(marked with red) on iOS and Android are left:1mm right:1mm top:1.5mm bottom:1.5mm but they look different. The fields have the same issue on both devices. The height ratio of the component on android is more than on iOS.

The button "登入" UIID = "TestButton"
Derive setting
[image]
Padding setting
[image]

Button with TestButton Style on Android device- Galaxy A31
[image]

Button with object inspector and TestButton Style on Samsung S7 skin
[image]

Comment: Is this on a physical device or simulator?
Millimeter is a physical screen measurement so you would need more pixels on a higher DPI device to represent the same amount of millimeters but the size would appear similar when looking at the physical devices side by side. Having said that MM sizing isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: Both of them are from physical devices.
The iOS pic is from iPhone 7 Plus with 1080 x 1920 pixels 401 ppi
The Android pic is from Samsung A31 with 1080 x 2400 pixels 411 ppi 

The pic of iOS looks more likely to the pic from the simulator compared with the pic from android.

How do I make the button of the Samsung A31 look like iPhone 7 Plus's button with the same theme?

Comment: Check the density numbers and actual resolution on the Samsung. You might be falling into this problem on the Samsung device: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61752978/codename-one-app-running-in-lower-resolution-android

Comment: LG also has this issue. I think this issue is related to android devices running my app.
I try to solve this issue by setting the native scheme on cn1 designer from iOS 6 to ICS. and saving the theme file. But the setting changed back to iOS 6 when I reopened the theme file.

Comment: My Samsung device resolution on spec is 1080 x 2400 pixels. And The called value on my Samsung device getDisplayWidth()=1080 getDisplayHeight()=2282.
The called values are the same as the real device resolution.

Comment: You didn't override the inherit native theme functionality right? What are the density values returned from the device? Try this app on the devices to see what we detect from the OS: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/device-tester.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the meaning of "override the inherit native theme functionality". I have overrides padding left:1mm right:1mm top:1.5mm bottom:1.5mm for the weird button. The output of device-tester app is attached to the question.

Comment: The numbers look right. Density HD seems to be the correct value here. As far as I can tell this is reproducible on the simulator. So when you inspect the component in an iOS skin vs. an Android skin what do you see? What is occupying that area? Also try disabling the round border as a test to see if it's the source of the problem since it has its own padding override.

Comment: I add three pic Simulators with iPhone 7 skin, the Simulator with the Samsung Galaxy s7 skin and the Samsung A31 device with a line border. This issue is on an Android devices. I also add two pic with a calculator arranged by tablelayout on a iOS device(iPhone plus) and a android device(Samsung A31). You can see a big difference.

Comment: I'll try to create a new skin so it will be easier to reproduce in the simulator. I couldn't find a decent A31 PSD but I found one for S21 Ultra which I guess will produce even more of an issue than the physical device. Will that help?

Comment: I will try the S21 Ultra skin after you send it.

Comment: It's [here](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-skins/blob/master/OTA/SamsungGalaxyS21Ultra.skin?raw=true)

Comment: How do I add the skin? The skins option of the simulator menu occupied all the y space of the window I can't scroll down to the add new in the menu. See the screenshot in the question.

Comment: This seems excessive but we need a better way to express skins. Try deleting some skins from your system as a workaround. They are probably under the `~/.codenameone`.

Comment: I added two pictures of the Simulator with Samsung S21 Ultra.  See the screenshots at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Can you inspect the buttons on the simulators for iOS/Android using the component inspector to see why the size difference exists. I'm assuming the iOS version has greater padding. You can then experimentally change the CSS to see what's causing the padding. Is it a difference between the milometer unit or something else. Since the problem is reproducible in the simulator it should be reasonably easy to understand the root cause by playing with the device and the inspector.

Comment: I inspect the button "登入" on the iOS/Android skin. I also show the padding of the UIID = "h3lbtn". The "登入" button uses the same UIID = "h3lbtn" on both iOS and Android.

Comment: In both cases you see the same padding for the buttons? If you make the zoom 100% are they both sized the same (sans different font sizes)? Assuming not. How is the css style defined?

Comment: Yes, I see the same padding for the buttons in the simulator. The paddings for the buttons are different for comparing the simulator(both run on iOS/android skins) with the real android devices. 
How do I get the css style?

Comment: The paddings for buttons on real android devices are different from those on real iOS devices, android skins in simulators, and iOS skink in simulators.

Comment: So the Android simulator works correctly but the Android device doesn't? The simulators seem to behave as expected. I see a 7 pixel difference which would make sense for density calculations.

Comment: Yes, the Android simulator works correctly but the Android device doesn't.
The padding of the button issue is only on Android device.

Comment: I had a detailed answer and suddenly realized it's wrong. Look at your padding in the designer: 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1. So horizontal/vertical padding should be different. But on the simulator they're identical. It's hard to tell what went wrong but I guess there's a conflict in your styles and the right one isn't applied. If you selected to inherit another style turn that off as inheritance is flaky.

Comment: The padding setting Left:1 Right:1 Top:1.5 Bottom:1.5 The button is contained in a box layout; So the button expands to the whole space. I design a new style 'TestButton' which doesn't inherit another style. The result is the same. Android real device padding is different from others. Pls. refer to question.

Comment: Padding size won't change because of layout. How does the component look in the Component Inspector? Is the padding still symmetric?

Comment: I think it is. Pls. refer to the pic attached to the question.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this.  The problem was that it was rounding padding values to integers.  I have fixed this in git and it will be part of the next release next Friday.

Comment: Notice that this will fix the discrepancy in the horizontal/vertical padding but not the difference between Android and the simulator/iOS. We'll need to reproduce that to investigate.

Comment: How can I help you reproduce the issue?